# Override Sinatra default NotFound error page

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is there a way to override the sinatra default NotFound error page ("Sinatra doesnt know this ditty")? I want sinatra to show only a plain string as "Method not found" when it does not found the proper route, but when I raise an 404 error from inside a route I want it to show the passed-in error message.

Implementing the not_found block like this:

```
 not_found do
    'Method not found.' 
  end
```

works, but its not a valid option since I want to be able to throw my own NotFound error messages from routes like this:

```
 get '/' do
    begin
      # some processing that can raise an exception if resource not found
    rescue => e
      error 404, e.message.to_json
    end
  end
```

But as expected not_found block overrides my error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found that all routes are matched in order, so after all routes I put `get/post/put/delete '*' do ; end` and that solves my problem.

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps a more graceful solution than that proposed in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452253/override-sinatra-default-notfound-error-page#8472353) is to rescue only `Sinatra::NotFound`, rather than using the `error(404)` or `not_found` styles.

```
error Sinatra::NotFound do
  content_type 'text/plain'
  [404, 'Not Found']
end
```

This prevents the "sinatra doesn't know this ditty" default page for routes that you haven't defined, but doesn't get in the way of explicit `return [404, 'Something else']`-style responses.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use error handling in your route, you can utilize the built in `error` route like this (taken and modified from the [Sinatra: Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449304230) book)

```
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  set :show_exceptions, false
end

get '/div_by_zero' do
  0 / 0
  "You won't see me."
end

not_found do
  request.path
end

error do
  "Error is: " + params['captures'].first.inspect
end
```

There is a parameter `captures` that holds your error. You can access it via `params['captures']`. It is an array, and in my tests it would contain a single element, which was the error itself (not a string).

[Here is information on the request object.](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object)

Comment: I, that works but not for unmatched routes, so if I have a sinatra application like the one you posted and try to reach for example `/this_is_not_a_present_route` I still see the default sinatra page instead of the error message.

Comment: So if you have a request for a non-existent route, then use the `not_found` route. In the request object, there is `request.path` which would give you `'this_is_not_a_present_route'` in your example. I updated the example too.

Comment: Hi, the problem is how to do not override other 404 error messages raised from inside routes. That way it will always present the request.path if trying to reach a not implemented route but will to show it if some 404 error is raised from inside routes.

Comment: If you're raising an error from inside a route, you shouldn't be sending back a 404, you should sending back a 500 or even 503. 404 is for when the requested URI is not found.

Comment: In the example, `params['captures']` does not contain exceptions or error messages. It is populated with the regular expression captures if they are specified in the path (i.e., `get %r{/id/(\d+)} do end`). So this answer is off base. Use `env['sinatra.error']` to access the exception object.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `RACK_ENV=production` to disable the "Sinatra doesnt know this ditty" page. Sinatra uses another defaults in production.

Worked for me with Sinatra v3.1.0.
But according to the code on Github, it has been implemented since 2008 (~ v0.3.0), possibly even earlier:

- https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/a734cf38ac0e7ddee437c8d273de50f2a4053339/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L638
- https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/a734cf38ac0e7ddee437c8d273de50f2a4053339/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L645-L657