# override not_found sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
sinatra (= 1.4.5)
```

I want to render a custom 404 message for specific routes, in this case, the text 'Not found'

```
class App < Sinatra::Application 

  not_found do
    'You suck'
  end

  get '/404page' do
    halt 404, 'Not found'
  end 
end
```

I have found that no matter what I do, the text from the `not_found block` is invoked any time response status is set to 404, when all I really want is the text from the halt.

May be a duplicate of [Override Sinatra default NotFound error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452253/override-sinatra-default-notfound-error-page) but I have not been able to find the soution.

Answer (score 4):

Overriding `error Sinatra::NotFound` seems to be a better choice to handle 404 when a specific route is not found.

```
error Sinatra::NotFound do
  'You suck'
end

get '/404page' do
  halt 404, 'Not found'
end
```

Comment: This works for me since I have another `error 404 do` handler, so I can differentiate between my own 404 errors and a API endpoint miss (Sinatra::NotFound)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a body to not_found, so your get request would just look something like this.

```
get '/404page' do
  not_found('Not found')
end
```

This will call `halt 404, 'Not found'` via the not_found method.

More often than not this is what you will need; if this does not suit your needs then you would need to consider overriding the Sinatra `route_missing` method, which I have included below.

```
# No matching route was found or all routes passed. The default
# implementation is to forward the request downstream when running
# as middleware (@app is non-nil); when no downstream app is set, raise
# a NotFound exception. Subclasses can override this method to perform
# custom route miss logic.
def route_missing
  if @app
    forward
  else
    raise NotFound
  end
end
```